# Required permissions to upload sandbox solution

Tags: sandbox-solution, solution-package

I want to assign a user the minimum permissions to upload sandbox solution in the site collection, what's the required permission level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mostly true that you need to be a site collection administrator to deploy sandboxed solutions. However, a solution that does not contain an assembly is still able to be deployed by a user with "Full Control" privileges on the site collection root.

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825660/sharepoint-uploading-sandboxed-solutions-without-needing-to-be-an-administrator

Comment: I read that you don't need to be site collection admin to upload a solution, but to activate it, you need to be a site collection admin. How can there be an assembly in sandbox solution? isn't assemblies uploaded to server file system?

Comment: There can be an assembly but it wouldn't be deployed to a gac

Comment: where is it stored?

Comment: take a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4565793/1745230